# Write kernel system call that prints human readable time

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, system-calls

I'm trying to print the time within my own custom system call in a human readable format (Jan 29 2015 05:53:12 for example, though any order is fine). I'm using code I know works in a standard C program because I've used it before, but for some reason it doesn't work within a system call.

```
#include<linux/linkage.h>
#include<linux/kernel.h>
#include<linux/sched.h>
#include<linux/time.h>

asmlinkage long sys_mycall (int someVal)
{
    time_t t;
    time(&t);

    printk("myInt: %d", someVal);
    printk("%s", ctime(&t)) ;

    return 0 ;
}
```

I'm getting errors on implicit declaration of functions 'time' and 'ctime', even though I included linux/time.h (I also tried just time.h).
And an error on ctime returning type int when I specified %s.

I know this means that something is going wrong with the time.h, but what exactly is it? Am I not allowed to include that in a sys call?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The kernel coding environment is not a "hosted" implementation of C, which implies that various standard C functions like `ctime()` might not exist, or if they do, might not behave in the same way as the standard functions.  In fact, `ctime()` does not exist inside the kernel at all.

Instead, you can use `time_to_tm()` from `<linux/time.h>` to convert a `time_t` to a broken-down time in a `struct tm`, and then print the components of `struct tm` individually.

Note that you have to supply a timezone offset to `time_to_tm()`, because there is no overall "current timezone" for the kernel - timezone is a display setting and is therefore handled entirely in userspace.  This is one reason why the kernel typically doesn't format times to be "human-readable" itself.  If you don't have a good value to supply for the timezone offset, you can use zero which will mean that the broken-down time is in UTC.

Instead of `time()`, to obtain the current time to seconds granuality inside the kernel use `get_seconds()`.

Answer (score 0):

The `ctime()` function is not available in the kernel.

In fact, there are very few date/time formatting functions available in the kernel; most of these functions are only available in user space. If you want to generate a timestamp in the kernel, don't try to format it; just return a `time_t` and let userspace applications handle the formatting.

If that isn't enough and you **really** want a readable timestamp, you'll need to define the necessary functions yourself.